# How to scroll a view up to show EditText hidden by keyboard in a layout used in a dialog

Tags: android, keyboard, android-edittext, hide, scrollview

i'm developing an app in android. 
I have some edittext in horizontal linear layout. 
When users fill them, when scroll finishes to scroll, keyboard will hide the last 2-3 edittext and users can't write in the last edittext. What can i do? Can you help me? This is my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<ScrollView 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/sfondo">
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_marginTop="10dp">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView1" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Cognome e nome/rag.soc/azienda" android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_gravity="center"></TextView>
    <EditText android:id="@+id/editText1" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:inputType="textPersonName">
        <requestFocus></requestFocus>
    </EditText>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView2" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Partita iva / coe rsm" android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_gravity="center"></TextView>
    <EditText android:id="@+id/editText2" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></EditText>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView3" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Codice Fiscale" android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_gravity="center"></TextView>
    <EditText android:id="@+id/editText3" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></EditText>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView4" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Indirizzo" android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_gravity="center"></TextView>
    <EditText android:id="@+id/editText4" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></EditText>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView5" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="CAP" android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_gravity="center"></TextView>
    <EditText android:id="@+id/editText5" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></EditText>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView6" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Comune" android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_gravity="center"></TextView>
    <EditText android:id="@+id/editText6" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></EditText>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView7" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Provincia" android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_gravity="center"></TextView>
    <EditText android:id="@+id/editText7" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></EditText>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView8" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Telefono" android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_gravity="center"></TextView>
    <EditText android:id="@+id/editText8" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></EditText>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView9" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Fax" android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_gravity="center"></TextView>
    <EditText android:id="@+id/editText9" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></EditText>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView10"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Cellulare" android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_gravity="center"></TextView>
    <EditText android:id="@+id/editText10" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></EditText>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView11"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Email" android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_gravity="center"></TextView>
    <EditText android:id="@+id/editText11" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></EditText>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView12"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Ripeti Email" android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_gravity="center"></TextView>
    <EditText android:id="@+id/editText12" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></EditText>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView13"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Password" android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_gravity="center"></TextView>
    <EditText android:id="@+id/editText13" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword"></EditText>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView14"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Ripeti Password" android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_gravity="center"></TextView>
    <EditText android:id="@+id/editText14" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword"></EditText>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView15"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Note per la consegna" android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_gravity="center"></TextView>
    <EditText android:id="@+id/editText15" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></EditText>
    <ImageButton android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/invia_form"
        android:src="@drawable/invia"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:background="@null"></ImageButton>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
```

Answer (score 2):

In your Androidmanifest.xml,add below code for re-sizing layout components.

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"
```

Refer [android blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2009/04/updating-applications-for-on-screen.html) for controlling layout behavior while keyboard is shown.

Answer (score 1):

Change your activity in the manifest adding the attribute:

android:windowSoftInputMode

The right value in your case should be adjustResize. Check [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft) in case you have different needs

Comment: it is not an activity, but a dialog!

Comment: Is that a layout that you use for a dialog? You should adjust your question and give more info about it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want **resize the dialog when keyboard open** just write the bellow code before dialog's show method as

```
dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
dialog.show();
```